# Find anchors in string and wrap those with a header

Tags: java, html, jsp

Hi I'm pretty new with Java. And I can't figure out what a nice solution is for my problem. I would like to add a header, in this case an `H2` around the anchors in the following string.

Lets say `li.getContent().toString` contains the following:

```
<a href="http://test">TEST</a><div class="description">lorem ipsum</div>
```

With the following code:

```
for (Element li : liS) {
    out.append("<div class=\"result\">\n" +
               "\t\t\t<ul class=\"resultset\">\t\n" +
               "\t\t\t\t<li><div class=\"item\"> " + 
               li.getContent().toString() + "</div></li>\n" +
               "\t\t\t</ul>\n" + "\t\t</div>");
}
```

What I want to have is that `li.getContent().toString` shows like this, by adding the `H2` headers :

```
<h2><a href="http://test">TEST</a></h2><div class="description">lorem ipsum</div>
```

Is there some kind of wrap function where I can find the Anchor and wrap it with a header?

Comment: why don't you write your own wrap function?

Comment: Writing a wrap method is beyond trivial... I'm assuming he's asking about how to detect the links.

Comment: Yes I want to detect the links and then I would like to place the headers around it. :-)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6648499/778118) out.  There are a couple options listed in different answers.